# Set colour to wx.listbox item

Tags: python, linux, windows, wxpython, wxwidgets

Wxpython provides the following api to change wx.listbox items colour:

```
wx.ListBox.SetItemBackgroundColour(self, item, c)
```

and

```
wx.ListBox.SetItemForegroundColour(self, item, c)
```

For some reason this functions fail to do so in my linux and windows. 
Any one know why?

note that `wx.ListBox.SetOwnBackgroundColor` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is a limitation of the native widget. I've seen several widgets that you cannot set the background or foreground color of because that widget just doesn't support it on that platform, but it DOES support it on other platform(s). You can ask over on the wxPython mailing list to make sure though. They have some of the primary wx devs there.

In the meantime, youmight look at VListBox or maybe switch to a ListCtrl.

Comment: I see, but why is this information does not appear in documentation?

Comment: Because the current documentation is basically auto-generated by scripts from the docstrings / wxWidgets docs. The new Phoenix project is supposed to make contributing to the documentation much easier and will hopefully add lots more clarification of things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add wx.LB_OWNERDRAW style to your listbox

```
      self.list_box_1 = wx.ListBox(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, choices=["test1","test2"] ,style=wx.LB_OWNERDRAW)
      self.list_box_1.SetItemForegroundColour(1,wx.Colour(219, 112, 219))
```